# How to create a Word-like document (.docx) in an app?

Tags: iphone, ms-word, ipad

I would like to create a .docx file within an iPad application.  The file would be created within the app (the user would create/edit it like in Word--preferably with the same "feel" of Word) and then it would be saved as a .docx file.

So, is it possible to do this?  If so, how?  What other alternative file formats are there?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily generate [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) corresponding to most typical features of a word processor. It will not cover the vastness of available DOCX features, but I'm not certain a complete port of Microsoft Word to the iPhone would be practical, so most of these features would be unavailable anyway.

RTF is fully (read-write) supported by Microsoft Office and several other editors.

Comment: What would you use to edit the text that would preserve its formatting?